# sudo mysql won't open the shell

Tags: mysql, linux

I am starting to use MySQL server on my Ubuntu 20 machine and I am wondering why I can not open MySQL shell with `sudo mysql`.

The only thing I get is a message telling my that have to choose from

> Usage: /etc/init.d/mysql
> start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status.

How can I access the shell, because all the googling I have done, it is always `sudo mysql` and you are in.

=======Update===============

I figured out the problem, but that has raised another question that maybe someone reading this can help me to answer. It seems like the `sudo mysql`  command is calling mysql in the diretory  `/etc/init.d/mysql`, but if I do `sudo /usr/bin/mysql` then I can access the shell, but not the start|stop... commands.

My new question is, what is that I have to change to make `sudo mysql` refer to the `/usr/bin/mysql` directory, not the `/etc/init.d/mysql` one?

Comment: Is `MySQL` process running ? Try with `sudo service mysql status` , it would return something like `Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-11-25 15:02:30 UTC; 17h ago`

Comment: Check for more details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2075/whats-the-difference-between-service-and-etc-init-d

Comment: Yes, my mysql server is active. And I can do `sudo mysql start|stop|status ` etc, as the message above suggests, but I can NOT access the shell with simply `sudo mysql`

Comment: What is the error after you run `sudo mysql` ? Is it something like `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` ? If so run `sudo mysql -u user -p`

Comment: Every time I run mysql with sudo before I only get `Usage: /etc/init.d/mysql start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status.`, doesn't matter if it is `sudo mysql` or `sudo mysql -u user -p`. On the other hand if I run just `mysql -u user -p` (without sudo), I am asked for password and then denied as in  `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`. That was the original reason I wanted to go into the MySQL shell, to allow the root user to connect.